# How to get data source attributes from PostgreSQL and PostGIS layers

Tags: postgis, layers, pyqgis-3, data-source

I want to get attributes like schema name and table name from PostgreSQL and PostGIS loaded layers in QGIS 3. I've searched in API docs but just found about set data sources, anyone knows how to get this info?

Comment: you can see the complete DB connection string either when hovering over the layer or in the layer properties' *Information* tab. does that help? or are you looking for a way to get those values e.g. in *pyqgis*?

Comment: That's right @ThingumaBob I'm looking a way to get this values via pyqgis to do some tasks. I want to do a spatial join with tables which have same name but different schema.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the second part of the answer will help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246841/how-to-get-the-geometry-value-from-all-spatial-tables-in-postgresql-database/307171#307171

Comment: Unfortunately not @Cyril this answer is for pure SQL. I'm looking for a pyqgis method to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that it's simple, because the tool QGIS>properties>details   those data are generated...

Comment: @Francisco Camello does my answer helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information from your layer with the `source()` method. It returns the same string that you can see when you hover the layer in the legend, then you can parse it. As the postgres/postgis source contains sensitive data (e.g. password), you can alternatively use `publicSource()` to get only non-sensitive data.

example code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() #select a postgis layer before running that
source = layer.source()
public_source = layer.publicSource()
print source
print public_source
```